# css and z-index - making my submit button appear in and in-front of my search box

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've got a search box, the submit button of which I would like to have inside the box (a bit like bing) I've got some code from a couple of places which I hoped would do the job but I can't make the submit button appear on top of the search box

I've put together a fiddle but coz the image is on my machine it obviously doesn't pick it up, the code is there tho

http://jsfiddle.net/5a3Tr/1/

Anyone any ideas? I thought the z-index thing would work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `position: relative` from `input.rounded` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5a3Tr/3/)

Comment: Thanks boss. I don't even know why that was in there in the first place but removing it sorted it. Thanks :)